# access tab control for other form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

[image: Picture Of My Project]

I have a form 1 and form 2 in window form C#.in from 1 i have tabcontrol and function of add new tab , detect , and active tab which work fine in form 1 function are public , tabcontrol modifier is also public . But when i call same function in form 2 it does not work.

```
// form 1 function  
private void button_add_new_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_tab(textbox1.text);
}

private void button_active_tab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    active_tab(textbox1.text);
}

private void button_delect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    delect(textbox1.text);
}

public void add_tab(string str)
{
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(str);
    myTabPage.Name = str;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}

public void delect(string st)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(st);
}

public void active_tab(string st)
{
    tabControl1.SelectTab(st);
}

private void button_form2_show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage("Form  2 ");
    f.TopLevel = false;
    myTabPage.Name = "Form  2 ";
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(f);
    f.Show();
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    active_tab("Form  2 ");
}

// Form 2
```

Comment: So you want `Form2`, from within the `TabControl` on `Form1` to be able to add / delete pages to `Form1`'s `TabControl`? What is happening when you say "It doesn't work"?

Comment: control go to the add , detect and active functions but does not show any  effect on tab control like form1 button show  is i have to refresh the tab to show changes every with make changes from form2 or any other reason?  @sab669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the instance of Form1 to Form2 in the constructor.  Now call the public method in form2 button event by using form1 instance.